# How to handle totally no effort questions

Tags: discussion

I don't know how to respond to certain questions that show no effort at all from the OP. Like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837610/how-to-convert-xx-xxx-x-to-xx-xxx-x-regex-euro-writing-to-usa-writing

A simple google search would have given this OP the answer, how should I handle these questions? Flag them as too broad? In my opinion not the right one because there is just one correct answer. Please help me out on this one.

There was a question on this subject earlier, with no answer, but that's about code being attempted by a user.

I'm curious how you guys treat this kinda questions.

Comment: I would just downvote it.

Comment: Downvote and move on. Possibly vote to close as too broad if you really feel strongly.

Comment: Look at the voting tooltips.

Comment: I typically close the "Do my work for me" questions as "Too Broad" which I've done now.  The duplicate has a lot of discussion about it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of that question. My question indeed is a duplicate, but with that title, I don't feel ashamed I didn't found it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should downvote these questions (`This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`) and continue answering other questions. Don't worry about it too much, users who get downvoted a lot will either improve their questions or get a question ban. You can also improve the question yourself, if you feel it is salvageable.

You can flag the question as **Too Broad** if you feel the need to it, considering the following quote from the description of this flag:

> [...] or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details [...] to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.