# Code-Writing questions: What IS the proper flag to use?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I know that the title to this question will turn some people off and elicit thoughts to flag this question as a duplicate so I would like to say now that yes, I have read and seen [posts like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271863/misuse-of-off-topic-closure-reason/) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283252/new-close-reason-code-writing-request) that touch on this subject, but there is still one underlying question that I think has not been answered:

What IS the proper flag for questions that follow the form of "here is a coding question; please write code to help me"?

Looking at all these links, I see that it seems to be the general consensus on SO Meta that, yes, there should be a 'write code for me' vote-to-close flag (and this in itself may still be in debate among the community, so let's just ASSUME that it is true). However, it is evident that regardless of what I see, there ISN'T one for it. So what would be the most appropriate close reason for the time being? IS it appropriate to vote-to-close?

A little bit of background:
I have just recently (a few months) started going to SO to not ask questions/look for answers for coding queries but actually be an active member of SO and answer questions/comment for clarification/edit questions/ etc. Among this new list of things is flagging questions that seem to deserve flags. As I want to make sure I am not putting inappropriate flags and wrong edits, I want to clarify some things (and this may be useful for others who find themselves in the same position as me)

Comment: That's not a flag.  Its a close reason.  Flags are something else entirely.

Comment: If it isn't covered by a close reason (what you are referring to as flags,) don't vote to close it.

Comment: @JK yes, my bad, I have edited to reflect

Comment: @KevinB and thats what I mean by it may still be a debate: it is not currently covered and yet it seems that a question that is asking to write code will (almost always) be closed.

Comment: Highly related: [Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research)

Comment: @psubsee2003 not entirely related because I am asking more about questions that are just treating SO as a code-writing service but that IS quite an interesting question....

Comment: @RNar I'm looking at it from the opposite direction.  "Too board" is often the default close reason for code writing questions.  Definitely related, but probably less of a dup than I originally thought.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking at it upside down.  You are trying to find a catch-all close reason to fit every case, and you aren't going to find **one**.  The close reason, if there is one, is going to depend on the question.

First and foremost, most **close-worth** questions that are basically "write my code for me" are either "Too broad" or "Unclear what you are asking", and are often both.

- They can be too broad because without some more context, it could take novels to write a complete answer to address every possible facet of the question, or you can write a dozen or more different answers and have each one be peefectly valid.
- They can be unclear because it is unclear where the asker is stuck. Usually when both fit, I'll only use "unclear" when the asker never really asked a question and just pasted an assignment or a vague idea for a application.

Notice how I did not mention "Why isn't this code working" as an option.  I've seen and read of too many misuses of this close/flag reason.  If someone is not asking you to debug or fix a block of code without adequate info, don't use it.  When close reasons are used incorrectly, you risk getting them removed.

I'd also like to address the "close-worthy" phrase I bolded above.  As I discuss in my answer too [Is "too broad" a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research/283185#283185), a question asking for "How do I write code to do this" does not have to be too broad (or unclear).  Sometimes it is a perfectly valid question and all it needs is an answer (or maybe some editing, then an answer).

So to wrap up, the answer is no, there is no "proper" flag for code writing questions.  You need to judge each question on its own merits and apply the appropriate flag/close vote for the specific question.

Answer (score 3):

"Too broad" covers this in 99% of the cases.  The 1% of cases that you run into should be looked at critically; either they're incomplete (they want you to write the code because theirs is broken - they need more details to their question), or they're opinionated.  In *those* scenarios, flag appropriately.

Comment: this is what I had originally used (and probably will still continue to) but as in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274748/5323213) it sometimes seems as if 'Too broad' doesn't really fit.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: if too broad doesn't fit, don't use too broad. maybe the question doesn't need to be closed.